# Navigation show/hide not working Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-services

I just try to hide menu on Login Component, the property visible is set withing constructor of service but not working after that.

The value set with constructor is working fine but calling `hide()` function working fine in debugging but set hiddin/visible the navigation bar.

**navigation.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigationService {
  visible: boolean;

  constructor() { 
    this.visible = true; //It's working either set true or fasle 
  }

  hide() { 
    this.visible = false; //Function working fine but Not reflecting in UI
  }

}
```

**navigation.component.html**

```
<!--Main Navigation-->
<header *ngIf="nav.visible">
</header>
```

**login.componet.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { NavigationService } from '../../navigation.service';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(public nav: NavigationService) {
            this.nav.hide();
     }
      ngOnInit() {

      }
    }
```

**navigation.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationService } from '../../navigation.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss'],
  providers: [NavigationService]
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: ElementRef;
  clicked: boolean;
  constructor(public nav: NavigationService) {
    this.clicked = this.clicked === undefined ? false : true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setClicked(val: boolean): void {
    this.clicked = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: remove providers: [NavigationService] from login.component.ts

Comment: Removed but still not working

Comment: can you show navigation.component.ts?

Comment: can you show navigation.component.ts?

Comment: component Added @Asanka

Comment: remove `providers: [NavigationService] ` from navigation component as well. You want a **singleton** service.

Comment: Try moving the call to hide out of the constructor. 

As a general rule, try not to do anything in a constructor other than initialize vars to defaults or some such. Especially in a framework that depends on bound data to update views, you want to work with the component lifecycle, and the constructor isn't explicitly part of that. 
If ngOnInit doesn't work, try one of the other lifecycle hooks, though I think it'll probably do the trick. Even if it's not the fix, move it out of the constructor.

And of course this presumes that the value is actually updating, which you seem confident of.

Comment: you are not using a good way.please let me show a good way.

Comment: you can use behavioral subject or this method.as comments show this should be singleton if you use this.

Comment: Thanks @AJT_82 , It's works

Answer (score 1):

Removing providers from navigation component should work

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: ElementRef;
  clicked: boolean;
  constructor(public nav: NavigationService) {
    this.clicked = this.clicked === undefined ? false : true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  setClicked(val: boolean): void {
    this.clicked = val;
  }
}
```

please check stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o9jya9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavigation.service.ts